# Problems with buildbot shell command : Adding single quotes to last argc argument

Tags: buildbot

I am running buildbot v0.8.9 and encountering a really weird problem.

I try to change the access permissions of exe files and runs into troubles.

Here is the code I first wrote :

```
ShellCommand(command=["chmod", "u+rwx , "*.exe"],workdir="myWorkDir",descriptionDone=["Changing permission access"])
```

This result in :

`chmod u+rwx '*.exe'`

After I read that [article](http://trac.buildbot.net/wiki/FAQ) which seemed to be what I wanted, but after following it and doing :

```
ShellCommand(command=["sh", "chmod u+rwx *.exe"],workdir="myWorkDir",descriptionDone=["Changing permission access"])
```

I got this :

```
sh 'chmod u+rwx *.exe'
```

So the problem of the last argument single quoted is still there.

Comment: Try with triple quotes: command=['sh', '''chmod u+rwx *.exe''']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the response, reading the article I linked again since I had to do something else kind of related to that issue :

I wanted to use the "-c" argument, and I was missing it on my 2nd attempt.

So here is the correct code :

```
ShellCommand(command=["sh", "-c", "chmod u+rwx *.exe"],workdir="myWorkDir",descriptionDone=["Changing permission access"])
```